# two asp validations in one

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

how can I check for a regular expression (email) and make sure the field in a form is non-empty at the same time?
if I leave it to regular expression only, it accepts empty strings
if I place two validators, it takes the space for two labels, and sometimes both errors show next to each other, i only want one label for the error
thanks!

Comment: modifiy your regularexpression to validate empty string too

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful.

Comment: Set display to `dynamic` and it won't take two spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RequiredFieldValidator` and the `RegularExpressionValidator` and set [`Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display.aspx) to `Dynamic`, then it won't take two spaces.

> **Dynamic**: 
>   Space for the validation message is dynamically added to the page if validation fails.

In general it's a good idea to use two validators because you can provide two meaningful error-messages ("Please enter email" or "... must be a valid email").